# Error exporting the site field named "Parent Level"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, site-template

I am trying to save a site as a template. During this process it throws an error  "Error exporting the site field named "Parent Level".

Am I doing anything wrong?

Kind Regards,
Sepaka

Comment: Is `Parent Level` a lookup field? and it's a custom field or not?

Comment: I don't have any idea Kai. This has never happened before. I dont have a list or library with such name.

Comment: As message says this is a field, not a list. We had exactly the same error when in our lookup field definition was missing `Overwrite="TRUE"` attribute.

Comment: I get the exact same error, like this: _[SPException: Error exporting the site field named "Category".]_. It happens on any SPWeb (site) under the current SPSite. I have located 11 lists with either a InternalName or DisplayName set as _Category_ . All lists can be used normally and saved as list templates themselves. Most of the fields are Choice, and three are _TaxonomyFieldType_.

Comment: Is this a publishing site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for the "Overwrite=True" hint, which solved a problem I have spent 10 hours solve.

I have a SharePoint Sandboxed Solution which creates a SP Schema in a Subsite with a number og Lookup columns and this works fine when saving as a SP Template.  Now I am converting it to a Farm solution and I get this "Error exporting the site field named xxxx" awfull error....

Perfect!
Michael

Comment: Ideally, this should be a comment linking to a new question on the original question. It would help segregate the questions, for better searching and allow users to get the benefit of answering questions with correct answers.